# How to create a new razor page in VS2019?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages, custom-error-pages

I am following instructions on how to create a new razor page. So doing everything that the prof does but he gets a new page and I get a 404

I think my VS 2019 is not set up correctly. When I create a new Razor page even in an empty uncoded just default web app, I get this error "This localhost page can't be found" And URL to that new page adds %2F before the new page name like this

---

This localhost page can't be found
No webpage was found for the web address
http://localhost:53227/home/%2FExept%2FIndex

HTTP error 404

---

I can provide more clues, just not sure what is needed to be presented.

Thank you

Comment: `%2F` is the url encoded forward slash `/`.  Does your view name have spaces or other characters in it?

Comment: Can you share your Pages folder structure?And if you set routing with   `endpoints.MapRazorPages();` in your Startup.cs?

Comment: I just published to GitHub the whole project https://github.com/Sergento/mytestcodes/tree/master
I think I did it and shared it correctly.

Comment: You have created an MVC application, not a  Razor Pages app. Can you point to the instructions you are following?

Comment: I think it was the issue and my next sample app was created as a razor app which worked. Thank you for suggesting this.

Answer (score 0):

The 404 is a not fund indication, means the address is off.

I cloned your repos, all I had to do to get it to start was to mark the project, hit alt+enter and set the startup object to be you program.cs and everything started up beautifully

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I could not set startup to programs.cs but I did set it to Webapplicationform1 (name of the project) and it worked. Later I created another test project but did not choose MVC webapp and that worked as well with out changing anything.

Comment: @WorldonFire typically program.cs. has the entry point main function and it is it that starts your startup.cs, so it wouldn't start because the startup object was not defined in other words.